# How can I clear the white space over the text box in this Access report?

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

When I hit the button to open the report, the text box at the top is all white. This is because this text box has a rather large formula to generate its content.

[image]

The trick to fixing this is to simply click *anywhere else* on the report, like so:

[image]

How can I make it so that this report always clears this weird white space error? I was thinking there might be a way to add one more action in the macro that opens this report that tabs to the next control in the report or something. Does anyone know how to do this? Or if anyone has a different idea, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

This field looks like a simple title. Delete it simply.

Comment: The field is not a simple title. This field has a formula to generate its content. I cannot just "Delete it simply"

Comment: Hi loltospoon, from the text displayed in your screenshot "Location Inventory for: ..." I concluded, that the content of this field is meant for display only. A field to be used in further processing a shorter formula would have made more sence (eg. LN8200, or MM0000). Therefor my advice to delete it.

Comment: Alright, it took me some time to understand the problem. Select the field in the property window, chose the data section and set the enabled property to false. This way the field cannot be selected and is always displayed as when you click on the background. There should also be a property to define the colour of the selected text, but I couldn't find it right away. May be some else may enlighten us ;) about this point. Cheers.